# javascript function preventing postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, tabcontrol

I am using a javascript tab control and I have to use the below function along with the CSS for the links to act as a tab control... the problem is that as soon as I include this in my html,it prevents postback. As a result clicking a button on the 2nd tab moves it back to the 1st tab. Then I have to click the second tab again to get the result of the button click.

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs">
  <ul>
 <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="ui-tabs">My Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs">My AddressBook</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs"></div>
 <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs"></div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you defined `#tabs-1` twice. is it a typo?

Comment: do you have two div's with id `tabs-1`

Comment: the `.ui-tabs` divs are not closed

Comment: You should use UpdatePanel inside both tabs... Which will prevent changing the view.

Comment: works but creates other problems... data binding doesn't happen...